# Image of compact interval under continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

We know the image of a compact interval under continuous function is compact interval.
My doubt is, suppose a continuous function on closed and bounded interval $[a,b]$ is costant.
Then images reduces to a point, is a point a closed interval in $R$?

Comment: How do you define “interval”?

Comment: Yes, in this statement a singrl point is considered to be a degenerate interval.

Comment: @geetha290krm I disagree. A singleton is an interval, not a “degenerate interval”.

Answer (score 0):

$[a,b] = \{x \in \mathbb{R} : a \leq x \leq b\}$.

So, the interval $[a,a] =\{x \in \mathbb{R} : a \leq x \leq a\} $

But $a \leq x \leq a \implies x = a$, so $[a,a] = \{a\}$ is a degenerate interval.